# When a video starts on Cobalt 19, is there a callback that will alert me when video starts?

Tags: cobalt, remotecontrolevent

I need to handle the Play/Pause remote button which is sending the same code, I am able to toggle and send Play or Pause based on the previous key press, but I am trying to reset the toggle when video starts. For example, if video is paused, then the remote skips to the next track, the toggle is still in pause mode which would require the user to press play twice to get the next video to pause.

The source code is vast and I have been blindly searching for strings with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one physical key on a remote, send a `kSbKeyMediaPlayPause` key instead of trying to guess the state of a web app.